# Multithreaded ActiveRecord requests in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, multithreading, rspec

I'm trying to recreate a race condition in a test, so I can try out some solutions.  I find that in the threads I create in my test, ActiveRecord always returns 0 for counts and nil for finds.  For example, with 3 rows in the table "foos":

```
  it "whatever" do
    puts Foo.count
    5.times do
      Thread.new do
        puts Foo.count
      end
    end
  end
```

will print

```
3
0
0
0
0
0
```

test.log shows the expected query, the expected 6 times:

```
 SELECT count(*) AS count_all FROM `active_agents`
```

Any idea what's going on here?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'm assuming ActiveRecord opens a dedicated database connection for each thread. Since each RSpec example is wrapped inside a transaction, the other threads might not see the changes.

Try disabling transactional fixtures for that spec.

```
describe "thread test" do
  self.use_transactional_fixtures = false

  it "whatever" do
    puts Foo.count
    5.times do
      Thread.new do
        puts Foo.count
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I had the very same problem jeem is describing and @henning-koch's solution solved it for me. I added code to his solution above (needs to be accepted by someone else though).

Comment: This was solved for us when using `self.use_transactional_tests`. This is for the latest Rails version.